# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL setting a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, twig

I know that there is a few of this questions on SO but I cannot find any special character or quotes issue in the string.

I setting on page load some javascript variable like this:

```
current_attachment['og:description'] = "{{ content.objectDescription|e|nl2br }}";
```

And I end up with this string:

```
current_attachment['og:description'] = "Merci à tous les passionnés qui sont passés sur le stand Ducati admirer nos belles italiennes lors du Salon de la Moto. Et pour ceux qui n&#039;ont pas pu se déplacer : une petite photo de famille mêlant légendes et nouveautés, rien que pour vos yeux !<br />
<br />
Thanks";
```

And I have an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Comment: This is what I thought so I added the nl2br filter but I still have new lines in the string

Comment: I don't think there is any filter like this in twig. I'm already using `escape` and `nl2br`. I'll check further but I think I need to clean the string in JS.

Comment: Correct, just found this option :) Thanks for your help. If you post an answer with this information I'll accept it ;)

Comment: (I just deleted all my comments, since all the information made it into my answer; feel free to delete your own as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your string has newlines. In order to make your string safe for inclusion in a JavaScript string, you must use the [`escape`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/escape.html) filter with a `js` context argument:

```
{{ content.objectDescription|e('js') }}
```

The default operation for `escape` assumes you are placing the content directly into HTML, not a JS string.

If you want the `<br>`s in your original code (i.e., you ultimately use the string in an HTML context where `<br>`s are appropriate), you should add them *before* you apply `escape`:

```
{{ content.objectDescription|nl2br|e('js') }}
```

Comment: I don't believe the `|nl2br` in your answer actually does anything when you use it after the `|e`.

Answer (score 1):

[nl2br](http://php.net/nl2br) doesn't actually remove the newline/linebreaks, it just adds `<br>` tags so that the newlines will be "visible" in a browser (if you output the string in html context).

`|e('js')` will replace pretty much all non-alphanumeric characters with their unicode escape sequences, i.e. `\xXX` and `\uHHHH`, and will make the string not-very-pretty to look at (when viewing the source).

Thus, I prefer using [`|json_encode`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/json_encode.html), which makes sure the value you're encoding is a proper javascript literal (e.g. a literal string), but without all the ugly escape sequences. Note that if you're encoding a string, the output will *include* the quotes that enclose the string.

When outputting the value and [autoescaping](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/autoescape.html) is in effect (as is often the default), make sure to add the [`|raw`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html) filter so that autoescaping doesn't change the `"`s that enclose the string into `&quot;`s.

Solution (my suggestion):

```
current_attachment['og:description'] = {{ content.objectDescription|json_encode|raw }};
```